# Using SSL in Haskell

Tags: networking, haskell, ssl

Is there a complete(and good) implementation or wrapper for SSL in Haskell? My friend who is learning Haskell asked me earlier how to do TLS or SSL in Haskell, and after a little looking I couldn't give him a good answer.

hsgnutls appears to have never taken off, and hsopenssl seems to be an incomplete implementation, after a little Googling and StackOverflow search I didn't find a simple "This is how you do it." explanation. Is there a defacto way that I am missing or are you stuck using a partially implemented library?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [tls](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls) package? It's the one used by the Yesod framework and related packages, so it should be well maintained. (Though, I don't have any experience with it myself, so I can't comment on its completeness).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at either [HsOpenSSL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HsOpenSSL) or [tls](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tls)?

*HsOpenSSL* is a binding to OpenSSL, and *tls* is a Haskell implementation of TLS.

Comment: Worked for my friend, I had forgotten about this, thanks for the response, although the implementation is still incomplete looks like it serveed his needs.